# Find datacontext for commandparameter from itemcontainerstyle

Tags: wpf

I have a window with a treeview inside it. The window has a viewmodel and the treeview items are coming from my viewmodel.

I have a contextmenu for my treeview which is dynamically generated based on the selections made on the treeview.I have a property in my viewmodel with all selected nodes on the treeview which is populating correctly.

My dynamically generated contextmenuitems is binded to a command and the command parameter comes from my viewmodel or my main windows datacontext. I'm trying to set the command parameter binding inside my contextmenu itemcontainerstyle, but it keeps complaining that it's not able to find the context.

Here is my xaml code which lies in my MainWindow.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" x:Name="treeView">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuItemCommand}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedModels}"/>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ContextMenu>
    </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```

Now my viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel:NotificationObject
{
    private readonly IMenuRepository _menuRepository;

    public MyViewModel(IMenuRepository menuRepository)
    {
        _menuRepository = menuRepository;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _nodes;
    public ObservableCollection<string > Nodes
    {
        get { return _nodes; }
        set
        {
            _nodes = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Nodes);  
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedModels;
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedModels
    {
        get { return _selectedModels; }
        set
        {
            _selectedModels = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedModels);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyMenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get {return  _menuRepository.GetAll(SelectedModels); }
    }
}
```

..and my MenuItem viewmodel

```
public class MyMenuItem:NotificationObject
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name);   
        }
    }

    private DelegateCommand<IEnumerable<string>> _menuItemCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<IEnumerable<string>>  MenuItemCommand
    {
        get { return _menuItemCommand; }
        set
        {
            _menuItemCommand = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => MenuItemCommand);    
        }
    }
}
```

The menu items are getting generated correctly, and the command is binding correctly as well. However the command is grayed out and I can see an error in my output window which says:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'DataContext' property not found on 'object' ''DeleteMenuItem' (HashCode=20916652)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.SelectedModels; DataItem='DeleteMenuItem' (HashCode=20916652); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

Can you please tell me how to bind this correctly?

*NOTE*: I thought it was the binding, but even if binding is set appropriately, the menu item is grayed out. Can you please help? The framework is .NET 3.5

Thanks,
-Mike

Answer (score 0):

Hi if I have'nt misunderstood your question try this

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" Tag="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
        <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MenuItemCommand}"/>
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Tag.DataContext.SelectedModels}"/>
            </Style>
        </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ContextMenu>
```

Since your other binding is working so not to bother that make use of Tag Property.I hope this will give u an idea.